# When parsing a JSON response: fatal error: array cannot be bridged from Objective-C

Tags: ios, json, swift

I receive the runtime error: fatal error: array cannot be bridged from Objective-C

My code is the following:

```
func postCheckUserPhonenumbers(phonenumbers:[String], completionHandler: (([AnyObject?], AnyObject?) -> Void)) {
    let urlString = Constant.apiUrl().stringByAppendingFormat(Constant.apiPostCheckUserPhonenumbers)

    let phoneNumbersDictionary = phonenumbers.map({ ["number": $0] })

    let inputJSON = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(phoneNumbersDictionary, options: [])

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = inputJSON

    Alamofire.request(request).validate().responseJSON(completionHandler: {response in
        if response.result.isSuccess{
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                let jsonString = json.rawString()
                if let users:Array<User> = Mapper<User>().mapArray(jsonString) {
                    completionHandler(users, nil)
                } else {
                    completionHandler([nil], nil)
                }
            }
        }
        if response.result.isFailure{
            let message = ApiMessage()
            message.message = "No users found"
            completionHandler([nil],message)
        }
    })
}
```

This is what my debugger looks like:

[image]

Comment: Swift is more flexible for parse JSON. Just use Swifty solution to eliminate this type of errors. For reference see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595698/parse-json-with-swift-3?noredirect=1#comment66625071_39595698

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
func postCheckUserPhonenumbers(phonenumbers:[String], completionHandler: (([AnyObject]?, AnyObject?) -> Void)) {
    let urlString = Constant.apiUrl().stringByAppendingFormat(Constant.apiPostCheckUserPhonenumbers)

    let phoneNumbersDictionary = phonenumbers.map({ ["number": $0] })

    let inputJSON = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(phoneNumbersDictionary, options: [])

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = inputJSON

    Alamofire.request(request).validate().responseJSON(completionHandler: {response in
        if response.result.isSuccess{
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                let jsonString = json.rawString()
                if let users:Array<User> = Mapper<User>().mapArray(jsonString) {
                    completionHandler(users, nil)
                } else {
                    completionHandler(nil, nil)
                }
            }
        }
        if response.result.isFailure{
            let message = ApiMessage()
            message.message = "No users found"
            completionHandler(nil,message)
        }
    })
}
```

Can you spot the difference? Do a control + F and then search for '?'